# TypeError at /index/ -- 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

from django.shortcuts import render

## Create your views here.

def index(request):

```
title = 'You are not registered in the site'
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    title = "Welcome  %s" %(request.user) 

context = {
    "template_title" : title
}
return render(request, 'mysite/index.html',context)
```

Comment: He gives me this message? Where is the mistake !

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a user is authenticated, you need to do this `request.user.is_authenticated`.

*is_authenticated* is no longer a callable from version 2.*, but instead it returns a Boolean value. So remove the `()` at the end.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated: # <--- here
    title = "Welcome  %s" %(request.user)
```